# How can I retrieve all data users photo from firebase realtime database in a Flatlist?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-native-flatlist

I am having trouble rendering all users photo (not the current user) from my firebase realtime database into a Flatlist using React Native.
I can retrieve all users data using the function firebase.database().ref('users').once('value') and place this data into a list but I'm not sure how I can create a flatlist for this. I get a blank screen in the simulator from the below code. I am a beginner using react native. Can someone please assist? Below is my code and database structure for the users.

```
   export default class UniBoardScreen extends PureComponent {

   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     boardPosts: [],
   };

   var that = this;
  
firebase.database().ref(`users`).once(`value`).then(function(snapshot) 
  {
    that.setState({
    boardPosts:  snapshot.val(),
    });
  });
}
                                  

renderPost = post => {
   return (
  <TouchableOpacity>

<View >
  <Image source={{uri: post.board_cover_photo.sourceURL}} style={{ 
    margin:1, width:123, height:123, bottom:0 }}/>
</View>

  </TouchableOpacity>
   )
};

render() {

return (
 <View >
 <FlatList 
    style={styles.feed} 
    data={this.state.boardPosts}
    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderPost(item)}
    keyExtractor={item => item}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    numColumns={numColumns} 
 />
 </View>
   );
}
```

}

Users in firebase database:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in the logs or anything? You can check your terminal where you ran `npx react-native start` or run `npx react-native log-<ios/android>`. 
It would also be prudent when posting here to format your code snippets appropriately (indentation, syntax, etc.) SO has some decent guides as to how to add syntax highlighting also. 
In general, you want to make sure you're getting data. Can you put in a `console.log(post)` in the first line of your `renderPost` method? It would confirm you're getting data or not.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Apologies for the poor indenting in my code. So I added console.log(post) in the first line of the renderPost method but nothing was logged when I re-ran.

Comment: The other thing you can try is doing a `.catch(error => console.log(error))` after the `.then` on the firebase call. It's possible you're not actually retrieving the data properly.

Comment: But if you're also just getting a blank screen, I would just try rendering some text first to make sure React Native is happy with you. Just do a `return <View><Text>Hello World</Text></View>);` just to make sure.

Comment: The flatlist renders fine when I use an example dummy data like var posts = [
           {
  "key": "Property1",
  "image": “1xxx.jpg”}, { "key": "Property2", 
                 "street": "Pricey Close, Holland Park, W12", "image": “2.jpg”,}]. Also, the firebase call works. The console.log(this.state. boardPosts) returns the expected array -  {"0HZMNuuKSAY25KP2DpisSdiW4Kg1": {"board_cover_photo": {"creationDate": "1344461390", "filename": "IMG_0004.JPG", "height": 2500, "localIdentifier":  ....etc

Comment: Could it be the format of the array firebase returns that's causing the problem for the FlatList not to render? Would I need to change the list returned from Firebase into the example dummy list shown above?

Comment: Yeah, flatlist definitely needs an array. what you posted from the firebase response just looks like an object. You'll want to make sure it's for sure an array. But something like that should throw an error, I would think. But React Native can be finicky sometimes. Check the logs and such to see if it's breaking silently on you. It's a possibility.